# Pandas apply function to each row of a dataframe to return one or more new rows per entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataset like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[[{'name': 'Joe', 'age': 32, 'category': 'A'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 35, 'category': 'A'}]],
                   [[{'name': 'Beth', 'age': 33, 'category': 'B'}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 32, 'category': 'B'}]],
                   [[{'name': 'John', 'age': 35, 'category': 'C'}]],
                   [[{'name': 'Jill', 'age': 33, 'category': 'D'}]],
                   ], columns=['Entries'])
```

The dataframe has a single column (named 'Entries'), where each row contains a list of one or more dictionaries.

I need a way to convert the dataframe for each key in the dictionary to become a column, and for the values to appear in those corresponding columns, like so:

```
    age category  name
0  32.0        A   Joe
1  35.0        A  Jane
2  33.0        B  Beth
3  32.0        B   Bob
4  35.0        C  John
5  33.0        D  Jill
```

Currently I have the following code to do this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for entry in row.Entries:
        name = entry['name']
        age = entry['age']
        category = entry['category']

        single_entry = pd.Series({'name': name, 'age': age, 'category': category})
        df2 = df2.append(single_entry, ignore_index=True)
```

The code above works fine, but is very slow on my actual dataset, which has over 1,000,000 rows.

I considered using built-in Pandas functions to leverage their speed gains, for example the apply function, but I don't know how to apply this to this particular problem.

What is a more efficient way to achieve the above result?

Comment: @anky_91 no worry , if you would like post it, please go ahead ,since I change to another method ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use list comprehension with flatten values for improve speed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['Entries'] for y in x])
```

Another idea:

```
from  itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df['Entries'].tolist()))
```

---

```
print (df)
   name  age category
0   Joe   32        A
1  Jane   35        A
2  Beth   33        B
3   Bob   32        B
4  John   35        C
5  Jill   33        D
```

**Performance** with sample data repeated 10000 times for 40k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [222]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['Entries'] for y in x])
66.1 ms ± 770 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [223]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df['Entries'].tolist()))
60.9 ms ± 691 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
In [224]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain(*df.Entries.tolist()))
60.8 ms ± 237 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [225]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(sum(df.Entries.tolist(),[]))
3.94 s ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [226]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df['Entries'].explode().tolist())
131 ms ± 3.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retain index from the records, explode would help

```
s=df['Entries'].explode()
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)
```

---

```
   name  age category
0   Joe   32        A
0  Jane   35        A
1  Beth   33        B
1   Bob   32        B
2  John   35        C
3  Jill   33        D
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
pd.DataFrame(sum(df.Entries.tolist(),[]))

   name  age category
0   Joe   32        A
1  Jane   35        A
2  Beth   33        B
3   Bob   32        B
4  John   35        C
5  Jill   33        D
```

Or

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain(*df.Entries.tolist()))
   name  age category
0   Joe   32        A
1  Jane   35        A
2  Beth   33        B
3   Bob   32        B
4  John   35        C
5  Jill   33        D
```

Comment: ha ha , i posted the same again :P

Comment: @anky_91 why not use explode ~ , since that one have more information , it will keep the original index as well :-)